# ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «PROCEDURE»

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE transfer(INT, INT, DEC)
LANGUAGE plpgsql    
AS $$
BEGIN
    -- subtracting the amount from the sender's account 
    UPDATE accounts 
    SET balance = balance - $3
    WHERE id = $1;

    -- adding the amount to the receiver's account
    UPDATE accounts 
    SET balance = balance + $3
    WHERE id = $2;

    COMMIT;
END;

$$;
```

Comment: Bienvenido Auxiliar De Tecnología a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que versión de PostgreSQL estas utilizando, pues los procedures llegaron en la versión 11 de PostgreSQL, antes de esa versión todo debe ser una función y si quieres que se comporte como una procedure antes debes definirlo con retorno del tipo de datos void.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], la zona de respuestas no es espacio para dejarle comentarios o dudas al OP